# Excel ComboBox - Autosize Dropdown Only

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to have just the drop down menu of a ComboBox in a UserForm autofit to the text size, without changing the actual size of the ComboBox?

I've found some answers on how to autofit the actual ComboBox based on the values within, but that makes the size bigger than I actually want ([link here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=55098)).

The following image somewhat represents what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Comment: Are you filling the dropdown from a range?

Comment: Populating from a SQL query

Comment: If the data was on a worksheet Mat's Mug shows you how to do it here: [Populating a ComboBox from a Range](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140995/populating-a-combobox-from-a-range/140999#140999).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the columns seem a little wide, but over all I think the code does a pretty good job of configuring the drop down.

[image]

```
Private Sub ConfigureComboBox()
    Dim arrData, arrWidths
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, ListWidth As Double
    arrData = ComboBox1.List
    ReDim arrWidths(UBound(arrData, 2))

    For x = 0 To UBound(arrData, 1)
        For y = 0 To UBound(arrData, 2)

            If Len(arrData(x, y)) > arrWidths(y) Then arrWidths(y) = Len(arrData(x, y))

        Next
    Next

    For y = 0 To UBound(arrWidths)

        arrWidths(y) = arrWidths(y) * ComboBox1.Font.Size
        ListWidth = ListWidth + arrWidths(y)
    Next

    With ComboBox1
        .ColumnCount = UBound(arrWidths) + 1
        .ColumnWidths = Join(arrWidths, ";")
        .ListWidth = ListWidth
    End With

End Sub
```

Sample data from [Excel Sample Data](http://www.contextures.com/xlSampleData01.html#download)

Answer (score 0):

Me.ComboBox1.ListWidth = 200 'Custom size