# Autosize Dropdown List Content Only in ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm looking for a way to enlarge the Dropdown list of a combobox to show full width content. My combobox is a set width on my userform, but when you open the list the content is wider than the dropdown window.

I found a post that does what I'm looking for, but it is for an array list.
[Excel ComboBox - Autosize Dropdown Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624018/excel-combobox-autosize-dropdown-only/39626351). I'm populating my lists from a single column in an Excel page.

```vb
Private Sub ConfigureComboBox()
    Dim arrData, arrWidths
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, ListWidth As Double
    arrData = ComboBox1.List
    ReDim arrWidths(UBound(arrData, 2))
    
    For x = 0 To UBound(arrData, 1)
        For y = 0 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            If Len(arrData(x, y)) > arrWidths(y) Then arrWidths(y) = Len(arrData(x, y))
        Next
    Next
    
    For y = 0 To UBound(arrWidths)
        arrWidths(y) = arrWidths(y) * ComboBox1.Font.Size
        ListWidth = ListWidth + arrWidths(y)
    Next
    
    With ComboBox1
        .ColumnCount = UBound(arrWidths) + 1
        .ColumnWidths = Join(arrWidths, ";")
        .ListWidth = ListWidth
    End With
    
End Sub
```

The text is cut off by the list width.
[image]

I'm trying to do this.
[image]
The combobox stays the size on the form, but the dropdown list is larger to show the complete text in my column.

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify what you're getting vs what you're looking for? Are you asking about the list width, the column widths, or how to populate the dropdown from worksheet cells?

Comment: If the latter, try `arrData = Application.Transpose(YourSourceSheet.Range("YourSourceRange").Value)`; that should give you a one-dimensional variant array with the values in `YourSourceRange`.

Comment: Posted an Approach using a testing TextBox to autosize the n longest strings found in a column and assign them to a given combobox. BTW you can assign both a 1-dim as well as a 2-dim array to the box'es `.List` property, so no need of transposing to get a one-dimensional array :-)  @Malachilee

Answer (score 0):

**Autosize DropDown List Contents**

The approach below demonstrates how to

1. define the needed data range (1 column),
2. assign the column items to a variant array,
3. get the individual string lengths and extract e.g. the 10 longest strings as  test set,
4. autosize this set in a loop via a hidden textBox created on the fly and assign all data to the combobox'es `.List` property.

```
Sub ConfigureCombo(ByRef myComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox, _
                   mySheet As Worksheet, _
                   Optional myCol$ = "A", _
                   Optional myFontSize# = 10, Optional Startrow& = 2)
' Purpose: assign autosized items to combobox (by testing the n longest items)
' Note:    neglects a possible title row by default if no explicit Startrow argument is passed
' Author:  T.M. 2019-11-15 (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m)
  ' [1] Define data range and set object to memory
    Dim rng As Range, lastRow&
    lastRow = mySheet.Range(myCol & mySheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = mySheet.Range(myCol & Startrow & ":" & myCol & lastRow)  ' e.g. Sheet1.Range("B2:B6")
  ' [2] Get strings
    Dim v                                               ' declare variant array to hold strings
    v = rng.Value2                                      ' assign data to 1-based 2-dim array
  ' [3] Get string lengths
    Dim lengths                                         ' declare variant array to hold lengths
    lengths = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("len('" & _
              rng.Cells.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Address & ")"))
  ' [4] Autosize e.g. the 10 longest strings via testing text box created on the fly
    With Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "myTextBox") ' testing text box on the fly
        myComboBox.Font.Size = myFontSize                ' assign identical font sizes
        .Font.Size = myFontSize                          '
        .Top = -100                                      ' hide newly created textbox

        Dim n&, pos&, optWidth#
        For n = 1 To 10                                  ' check e.g. the 10 longest strings
            If n > UBound(lengths) Then Exit For         ' escape if less items than n
            pos = Application.Match(Application.Large(lengths, n), _
                lengths, 0)                              ' find nth position in lengths array
            lengths(pos) = lengths(pos) + 0.01           ' remove current length from lengths set
            .Text = v(pos, 1)                            ' enter next longest string to test textbox
            .AutoSize = True                             ' autosize test string
            If .Width + 6 > optWidth Then optWidth = .Width + 6
        Next n
    End With
  ' [5] Correct to final combobox width and assign data
    myComboBox.Width = optWidth                         ' assign best fit width
    myComboBox.List = v                                 ' assign data to combobox
End Sub
```

**Example call**

A possible example call using the worksheet's `CodeName` (e.g. `Sheet1`), referring to data column `B` together with a font size of 16 points could be as follows (you might want to call this via a command button click Event or also from the Initialize Event):

```
ConfigureCombo Me.ComboBox1, Sheet1, myCol:="B", myFontSize:=16
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Me.ComboBox1.ListWidth = 200 'Custom size
```